# Need to reload/recalculate NSArray

Tags: ios, arrays, database, nsdictionary

I hope someone can help, I'm at my wits end trying to figure this out!

Basically I have a JSON feed pulling data into an `NSDictionary` with an additional file (.h and .m) adding some conditional fields in relation to the current time. I need to update/refresh the conditional fields every x minutes without reloading/pulling the data from the JSON feed. Instead I'd like to re-run the conditional test and update the database with the initially created database.

Has anyone got any clue how to do this, I've research everywhere and cant find the answer!!

FYI here is the conditional argument to set the extra fields/entity in the database:

```
//
//  Entity.m
//  tabbed
//
//  Created by administrator on 16.07.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __HappyTimes__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RestarauntEntity.h"
#import "NSDate+DeviceDate.h"

@implementation RestarauntEntity

@synthesize city = _city;
@synthesize closingTime = _closingTime;
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize lattitude = _lattitude;
@synthesize longditude = _longditude;
@synthesize openingState = _openingState;
@synthesize openingTime = _openingTime;
@synthesize phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
@synthesize thumbnailUrl = _thumbnailUrl;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize website = _website;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *) dictionary 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
        _description = [dictionary objectForKey:@"content"]; 
        _thumbnailUrl = [dictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        _city = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"City"] objectAtIndex:0];
        _phoneNumber = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Phone Number"] objectAtIndex:0];
        _website = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Address"] objectAtIndex:0];


        // get opening/closing time values
        NSString *currentWeekDayName = [NSDate currentDayOfTheWeekInEnglish];        
        NSString *openingTimeForCurentDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Opening Time", currentWeekDayName];
        NSString *closingTimeForCurentDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Closing Time", currentWeekDayName];

        _openingTime = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:openingTimeForCurentDay] objectAtIndex:0];
        _closingTime = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:closingTimeForCurentDay] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Prepare current day string in format yyyy-MM-dd
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd "];
        [timeFormat setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
        [timeFormat setAMSymbol:@"am"];

        NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSString *currentDay = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

        // Find full date for opening and close time
        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];

        NSDate *openingTimeDate = [timeFormat dateFromString:[currentDay stringByAppendingString:_openingTime]];
        NSDate *closingTimeDate = [timeFormat dateFromString:[currentDay stringByAppendingString:_closingTime]];

        // Find out opening state of the restaraunt
        if(([openingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending) || ([openingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedSame)) {
            if([closingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateOpen;
            } else {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateClosed; 
            }
        } else {
            NSDate *nowPlusTwoHours = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:7200.0];
            if(([openingTimeDate compare:nowPlusTwoHours] == NSOrderedAscending) || ([openingTimeDate compare:nowPlusTwoHours] == NSOrderedSame))
            {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateWillBeOpenedInTwoHours;
            } else {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateClosed;
            }
        }

   //     _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateWillBeOpenedInTwoHours;

        NSArray *lattitudeRecord = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Lattitude"]; 
        _lattitude = [[lattitudeRecord objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

        NSArray *longditudeRecord = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Longditude"]; 
        _longditude = [[longditudeRecord objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    }

    //[setValue:@"RestarauntOpeningStateOpen" forKey:@"_openingState"];

  //  _openingState setValue:@"RestarauntOpeningStateOpen" forKeyPath:RestarauntOpeningState;

    return self;
}

//-(void)setValue:(id)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath{
//    _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateOpen;
//}

//-(void)setValue:(id)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath{
//    _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateOpen;
//}

@end
```

Comment: `code formatting` is for code, not emphasis. Also, your question is a code dump that you want somebody else to modify for you, which makes it low quality. Also, merely stating that you researched your problem doesn't qualify as research.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your input but I'm afraid you are completely wrong, I'm trying to learn here. Once again thank you for your low quality criticism and pompously assuming/arrogant input (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store the Opening State. This should be a computed property.
Create method that returns this value when requested:

```
- (OpeningState)openingState {
    OpeningState _openingState;

    NSDate *openingTimeDate = [timeFormat dateFromString:[currentDay stringByAppendingString:_openingTime]];
    NSDate *closingTimeDate = [timeFormat dateFromString:[currentDay stringByAppendingString:_closingTime]];

    // Find out opening state of the restaurant
    if(([openingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending) || ([openingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedSame)) {
        if([closingTimeDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateOpen;
            } else {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateClosed; 
            }
        } else {
            NSDate *nowPlusTwoHours = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:7200.0];
            if(([openingTimeDate compare:nowPlusTwoHours] == NSOrderedAscending) || ([openingTimeDate compare:nowPlusTwoHours] == NSOrderedSame))
            {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateWillBeOpenedInTwoHours;
            } else {
                _openingState = RestarauntOpeningStateClosed;
            }
        }
   return _openingState
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've had to edit a bit but certainly seems to do the job, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, you're a legend!!